# Converting a 2 channel stereo g729 file to individual single channel pcm encoded file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, encoding, asterisk

Whenever I try to convert a G729 encoded two channel file into mono channel pcm encoded wav files I get the following error

Input #0, wav, from 'g729stereo.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:07.07, bitrate: 16 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: g729 ([131][0][0][0] / 0x0083), 8000 Hz, 2 channels, 16 kb/s
[g729 @ 0x7fd163802a00] Only mono sound is supported (requested channels: 2).
Could not open codec for input stream 0

Can someone let me know what is the best way to proceed with it.

Comment: Have you tried using `sox`instead of `ffmpeg`?

Comment: G.729 actually only specifies monophonic audio. Where did you get the file?

Comment: this is from  Audio recoder software like Asterisx.

Comment: asterisk not support stereo g729 too

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the G729 codec that comes with ffmpeg only supports a single channel.

The best way to proceed is to upgrade to the newest version of ffmpeg, and see if support has improved.

If it hasn't, you can post a polite feature request with the ffmpeg developers, or sit down yourself and modify the G729 codec source code to implement it.
Or pay someone to do it for you, if you can't do it yourself.

Answer (score -2):

First use sox or other utility to split stereo to mono, after that decode and mix.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you give some explanation of how to go about doing this.

Comment: You have do some testing yourself. g729 stereo file is really rare thing. Try start from soxi to check if it really stereo, after that checkout https://www.nesono.com/node/275 or something similar.